# How to use Angular to conditionally set a second form value when a selection is made?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

Suppose I am creating a reservation system for a party.  Each guest must answer many questions to make a reservation, and among these are: "Are you at least 21 years old?", and "Do you plan to drink at the party?"  (We need to know how much beer to order!)

Suppose that I write the following as part of my Angular form:

```
<div>
    Are you at least 21 years old?
    <select ng-model="AgeGroup">
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        <option value='2'>No</option>
        <option value='3'>Maybe</option>
        <option value='4'>I don't know</option>
        <option value='5'>I refuse to answer</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    Do you plan to drink?
    <select ng-model="Drink">
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        <option value='2'>No</option>
        <option value='3'>Maybe</option>
        <option value='4'>I don't know</option>
        <option value='5'>I refuse to answer</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

(I put five selections here to make it more like my real problem.)

Suppose that I submit the above code to my supervisor who says, "This looks great, but I forgot to tell you part of the requirement: If the user gives any answer other than 'Yes' to 'Are you at least 21 years old, do not show the question 'Do you plan to drink?' and record 'No' as the answer to that question.

I think to myself that this is no problem!  I can simply use the `ng-if` directive to conditionally hide the second question.

I do this and set the condition to show the drinking question only if `AgeGroup === 1'`  So far, so good, that hides the drinking question when the user fails to specify that he is at least 21.

However, the above doesn't address the issue that the user's reservation must say that he is a non-drinker.

I have tried to do this by using the `ng-change` attribute to specify that when the user selects an answer other than "Yes" to "Are you at least 21 years old?", the model for "Do you plan to drink?" gets set to no, but this causes errors.

Now that I've rigged up Angular to hide the drinking question when the user fails to say he is at least 21, how do I set it up so that the `Drink` field in the model is "No"?

If at all possible, I would like to enforce this rule in the form rather than the controller.

Comment: What kind of errors are being caused by ng-change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `ng-change` to do it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/tnj22bcn/

```
<select ng-model="AgeGroup" ng-change="Drink = AgeGroup == 1 ? Drink : '2'">
```

Comment: Much cleaner than my approach. I like it.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you should watch the `AgeGroup` variable and modify the `Drink` value accordingly.

> Seeing @dave's approach. I would only use the watch approach if you need more logic to happen than can be done in an expression.

```
$scope.$watch('AgeGroup',function(newValue,oldValue){
  if(newValue !== '1') {
    $scope.Drink = '2';
    // other messaging / logic here.
  }
});
```

And in your template, you can disable the second select using `ng-disabled`.

```
<div>
    Are you at least 21 years old?
    <select ng-model="AgeGroup">
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        <option value='2'>No</option>
        <option value='3'>Maybe</option>
        <option value='4'>I don't know</option>
        <option value='5'>I refuse to answer</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    Do you plan to drink?
    <select ng-model="Drink" ng-disabled="AgeGroup !== '1'">
        <option value='1'>Yes</option>
        <option value='2'>No</option>
        <option value='3'>Maybe</option>
        <option value='4'>I don't know</option>
        <option value='5'>I refuse to answer</option>
    </select>
</div>
```